# How can I get year month and day from a string of numbers?

Tags: php, date, substr

I have a date that is given to me in the form `20111213 (YYYYMMDD)` and I am trying to separate the parts into day, month and year. I am using this code:

```
$day = substr($string, 6, 8);
$month = substr($string, 4, 6);
$year = substr($string, 0, 4);
$final = $day . "-" . $month . "-" . $year;
echo $final;
```

but that gives me the output

```
13-1213-2011
```

As you can see, the month gets interpreted as 4 characters and I can't get it just to output 12. Cheers for the help.

Comment: I know it's not completely related but take a look also at: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-parse.php like: date_parse("20111213") that does what you need!

Comment: Generally it is best to keep dates as dates for as long as possible before turning them into strings. Use [DateTime](http://www.php.net/datetime) as in my answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're misusing the third argument. It is the length of substring desired, not the ending position:

```
$day = substr($string, 6, 2);    // 2 char substring
$month = substr($string, 4, 2);  // 2 char substring
$year = substr($string, 0, 4);   // 4 char substring

$final = $day . "-" . $month . "-" . $year;
echo $final;
// 13-12-2011
```

[See the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) for correct usage.

Comment: Thanks, that worked but I need to wait 10 min before I can mark it as the approved answer.

Answer (score 1):

Read the manual [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) , the third parameter is `$length`

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
        $string = "20111213";
        $day = substr($string, 6, 2);
        $month = substr($string, 4, 2);
        $year = substr($string, 0, 4);
        $final = $day . "-" . $month . "-" . $year;
        echo $final;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var_dump(date('Y M d', strtotime('20111213')));
```

Output:-

> '2011 Dec 13'

You can modify the output anyway you like using the format string.

http://www.php.net/date
http://www.php.net/strtotime

Alternatively:-

```
$date = new DateTime('20111213');
$year = $date->format('Y');
$month = $date->format('M');
$day = $date->format('d');
echo "$year $month $day";
```

Output:-

> 2011 Dec 13

http://www.php.net/datetime

In all these examples exchange 'M' for 'm' in the format string to get '12' instead of 'Dec'.

If you are looking for this output "2011-12-13" then use

```
$date = new DateTime('20111213');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```